# In OCaml 4.03.0 FFI fails to compile with "No implementations provided" Error

Tags: ocaml, ffi

I upgraded my ocaml to 4.03.0.
Then, some wrapper libraries failed to build raising "No implemntations provided" Error.

I prepare a small example to explain my situation.

I write a C code in `hello_stubs.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<caml/mlvalues.h>
CAMLprim value caml_print_hello(value unit)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    return Val_unit;
}
```

Next, I prepare the interface file for ocaml, in `hello.mli`.

```
external print_hello : unit -> unit = "caml_print_hello"
```

Then, I code a main program in `main.ml`

```
Hello.print_hello();;
```

To compile these programs, I executed the following commands.

```
ocamlc -c hello.mli
ocamlc -c hello_stubs.c
ocamlopt -o main main.ml hello_stubs.o
```

Then, unfortunately, the last command failed with the following error message.

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Warning 58: no cmx file was found in path for module Hello, and its interface was not compiled with -opaque
File "main.ml", line 1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Hello referenced from main.cmx
```

According to the message,
I've tried `ocamlc -opaque hello.mli`, but it didn't solve the problem.

I also confirmed that the commands above work fine for ocaml 4.02.3.

Do you know how to compile this example with ocaml 4.03.0?

Answer (score 2):

The fix is easy: create `hello.ml` of the same contents of `hello.mli` and compile it and link for `main`.

I guess this is due to the following change of 4.03.0:

- PR#4166, PR#6956: force linking when calling external C primitives
  (Jacques Garrigue, reports by Markus Mottl and Christophe Troestler)

The related section of the reference manual should be updated.  See http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=7371